# Turn Off Secondary Display When Shutting Laptop Lid

Tags: windows-10, display, multiple-monitors

I noticed a lot of people want to keep their secondary display on when they shut the lid, but seeing as I don't want the computer to go to sleep or shift all my windows around every time I close the lid, I want to be able to disable both the secondary and primary displays when I close my lid.

The fn key to turn off the screen only works on the laptop's screen.

Comment: I'm looking for the same, did you find a way to turn off the secondary display?

Comment: nah, I just use my desktop now. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to power options and change your current plan settings then click on " change advanced power settings " you will find " Power buttons and lid " expand that then expand lid close action and set it to " do nothing "

Comment: Again, I just want to disable both displays when I shut the lid. I already have that setting done, but when I shut the lid since the computer does nothing it just thinks I want to turn off the laptop display and shifts all my windows around to the secondary monitor, then when I reopen the laptop puts them all on my laptop screen.